# Import data from two tables SQL + PK/FK

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to insert data from two different tables into this one:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customer CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INTEGER,
CompanyName VARCHAR(255),
ContactName VARCHAR(255),
ContactTitle VARCHAR(255),
Address VARCHAR(255),
City VARCHAR(255),
Region VARCHAR(255),
PostalCode VARCHAR(255),
Country VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID),
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Person(PhoneID)
);
```

**CustomerID** is *PK/FK* of **PhoneID** and **PhoneID** is in the table **Person**.

The other values are in the table **CustomerOrders**.

So I want to insert PhoneID into CustomerID and the rest of the data of CustomerOrders in the other variables.

I have proposed this:

```
  INSERT INTO customer (
     customerid,
     companyname,
     contactname,
     contacttitle,
     address,
     city,
     region,
     postalcode,
     country
)
     SELECT phoneid,
            companyname,
            contactname,
            contacttitle,
            address,
            city,
            region,
            postalcode,
            country
     FROM person,
          customerorders;
```

But when I compile it says:

> [2018-12-17 18:03:26] [23505] ERROR: duplicate key violates uniqueness
>   restriction «customer_pkey»
>
> [2018-12-17 18:03:26] Detail: The key already exists (customerid) =
>   (1).

In case I have not finished explaining well here I leave the model:

[image: model]

Comment: How CustomerID referencing to Persone(PersionID), Is CustomerID and PersionID is same?

Comment: Yes, they have to be the same. That's because is FK! @Vivek

Comment: Your design is strange.Why does `CustomerOrders`  store customer  information such as ContactName,Address etc? Is it going to remain that way or are you planning to normalize it? `select .. from person, customerorders` will lead to a `cross join` between the two tables and hence the duplicates. Moreover, I suspect `CustomerOrders` to have multiple orders per customer id. If that's right, you would have to check whether `DISTINCT` will work or you wish to insert  `MAX` or `MIN` of all other values.

Comment: Correct. I'm planning to normalize it.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query should have at least one join between both of tables until you don't want to make it cross. Anyway, you are getting the issue because of Inserting customerID already present.

```
    INSERT INTO Customer(CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country) 
    SELECT PhoneID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region , PostalCode, Country
    FROM Person p 
    JOIN CustomerOrders c
    ON p.PhoneID = c.CustomerID;
```

Comment: There's no other way to make it? I mean there's no alternative for not using **JOIN**? @Vivek

Comment: Unable to resolve column 'CustomerID' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection performs unresolved SQL references check. @Vivek

Comment: @PedroGarcía-Mauriño any way why you want to join the tables, In join you are going to join on `Person` table with `CustomerOrders` on `Person.PhoneID=CusotmerOrders.CustomerID` and at last making selection of `PhoneID` as `CustomerID` so you will get the same records, Hence the outcome is `You'll get all matching records from Customer with Person`.

Comment: If the above is the case then alternatively you can use `IN` clause to make this test  `INSERT INTO Customer(CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country) 
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region , PostalCode, Country
FROM  CustomerOrders
where CustomerID in (select PhoneID from Person);`